# Подскажите, как разрешить отправку формы без обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

Пишу валидацию данных формы. При неправильном вводе данных, появляется запрет на отправку формы, но при исправлении данных и повторной отправке - запрет действителен.

```
<script>

const EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/iu;
    const NUMBER_REGEXP = /^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$/;

    function isEmailValid(value) {
      return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(value);
    }

    function isTelValid(value) {
      return NUMBER_REGEXP.test(value);
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#email").change(function () {

        let input = document.getElementById('email');
        let form = document.querySelector('form');

        if (isEmailValid(input.value)) {
          input.style.borderColor = 'green';
        } else {
          input.style.borderColor = 'red';
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }

      });

      $("#tel").change(function () {

        let input1 = document.getElementById('tel');
        let form = document.querySelector('form');

        if (isTelValid(input1.value)) {
          input1.style.borderColor = 'green';
        } else {
          input1.style.borderColor = 'red';
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });

        }

      });


    });

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form th:action="'/new-order'" class="form" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="ivanov@mail.ru" required />
<input type="number" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="+7" required />
<button type="submit" id="form_submit">Подтверждение заказа</button>
</form>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, как можно повторять цикл проверки без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Про отправку многое можно почерпнуть в этой статье - https://snipp.ru/jquery/ajax-jquery

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp - почитайте и тут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const form = document.querySelector('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // ... тут логика отправки
})
```

Comment: Судя по вопросу ТСа, он вообще не в курсе что писать вместо `// ... тут логика отправки`...

Comment: @ksa планировался данный код `if (isTelValid(input1.value) && isEmailValid(input.value)) {
        this.submit()
      }`

Comment: @bodyauza, если тебе ответ **Meth0d** понятен - ставь ему `+`, делай "Ответ принят" (это флажок)...